# Forcing nlme to give the results for the levels of a treatment as "absolute" values instead of contrasts

Tags: r, categorical-data, contrasts, lme4-nlme

I am using a nonlinear model to fit an equation to data using `nlme` in R.

Several values (one by treatment) are estimated for a fixed effect. 
As usual, by default of `nlme`, the estimated values of this fixed effect
are given relative to the smallest value as contrasts.

I would like, instead, to have the results as "absolute" values of the 
fixed effect for each treatment.

My question is the following: how  can I specify to `nlme`  that contrasts
should not be used to give the estimates of the  values of this fixed effect by  treatment.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about how to use R without a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/1217536).

Comment: Many thanks for all answers. Sorry for not having provided the source in my question. Here it is : nlme.fit <- nlme(model = y ~ constrained.full.param.traj(a, a1, log(n0), x), data = my.data, method = "ML", fixed = list(a + a1 ~ 1, n0 ~ treat), random = a ~ 1 | pla, start = list(fixed = c(a = 13.7, a1 = 12.5, n0 = n0.start))) In nlme.fit, the smallest estimated value of n0 is given, but the other estimated values, for the rest of the treatments (treat), are given relative to this smallest value, as difference contrasts. J.-M. Ottorini

Comment: Correction: the default estimates are not relative to the smallest value. They are relative to the first level of the factor.

Answer (score 5):

This is just about how categorical variables are coded in R and how the forumlas work.  It doesn't really have anything to do with whether the model is nonlinear or if you use a mixed model.  The easiest way to get your model returned fitted with level means coding instead of reference level coding is to suppress the intercept when you have a factor variable.  In R, this can be done with either `+0` or `-1`.  Consider:

```
set.seed(123)                 # this makes the example exactly reproducible
x = runif(30, min=0, max=10)  # x is a continuous variable
g = as.factor(sample(rep(c("C","T"), 15), 30, replace=F))  # g is categorical
y = 3 + .3*x + 2*ifelse(g=="T",1,0) + rnorm(30)            

## this is the typical way, which uses reference level coding:  
mod.refL = lm(y~x+g)
summary(mod.refL)
# ...
# Coefficients:
#             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# (Intercept)  3.18841    0.41014   7.774 2.33e-08 ***
# x            0.28444    0.05557   5.118 2.22e-05 ***
# gT           2.15804    0.31838   6.778 2.80e-07 ***
# ...

## here I used '0' to suppress the intercept:  
mod.Lmeans = lm(y~0+x+g)
summary(mod.Lmeans)
# ...
# Coefficients:
#    Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
# x   0.28444    0.05557   5.118 2.22e-05 ***
# gC  3.18841    0.41014   7.774 2.33e-08 ***
# gT  5.34644    0.36615  14.602 2.46e-14 ***
# ...
```

Answer (score 2):

What you really want are predictions from the model at each treatment level. If it is just a one-factor experiment, with one covariate, do something like this:

```
grid <- data.frame(treat = c("t1", "t2", "t3"), covariate = c(rep(5.5,3))
predict(my.model, newdata = grid)
```

Of course, you should use the actual variable names and treatment levels you used. Typically, people would want to make the predictions at the mean value of each covariate.

[Earlier stuff with gung's example removed because it is linear. Also, note that his results with the second approach are predictions at `x = 0`, not `x` equal to its mean.].